# Is git flow development and master branch never merge again(parallel forever)?

Tags: git, git-flow

I read this [gitflow](https://datasift.github.io/gitflow/IntroducingGitFlow.html) article.

And it seems branch `develop` and branch `master` are parallel.
They will never be merged again.
(What I mean is:
`git checkout master`
`git merge develop`
`git checkout develop`
`git merge master`)

Is that right?
If the two branch are parallel, the team leader need to make sure the two branch has same code by himself, right ?

Answer (score 2):

`develop` and `master` do indeed run in parallel in a mathematical sense. However, there should not be 'parallel development' going on -- development should only be occurring on branches stemming from `develop` - never `master`.

Assuming proper Git Flow is followed, no intervention is required to make sure the code branches are identical (and in fact, `develop` is nearly always significantly ahead of `master`).

You should never be making changes on `master` directly, and `master` should merely be treated as a 'last known good state' of your project. **ONLY** `release` branches should ever be merged into `master` (as, in theory, you would only ever want to release good to the public that is in a good state).

All code that reaches `master` will have originally been in `develop` at one point. You should work on `feature` branches that get merged to `develop` once complete, and then this code *eventually* makes its way into the `master` branch after a release.

This is done through a `release` branch, which is a point in time where you are happy with the work that has been completed thoroughly, and think that the code is ready for exposure to the public. This `release` branch is what should be deployed out to your production server (after proper testing). It should also be tagged with the version you are deploying (such as `1.0.1` or `1.0.2`).

If there is a (severe) problem with the release that was only found after releasing, you can create a `hotfix` branch to resolve it. In theory, this branch is based off of the `release` branched and merged back to the `release` branch. Often this can be done directly on the `release` branch itself, however. If there is a minor problem, yu may wish to leave it until the next official release.

After deployment, you merge the `release` branch to `master` -- you're happy that the deployment went well, and are confident that the code is in a good state. In *addition* to merging the `release` branch to `master` (indicating that you are  indeed at a 'safe' point in your project), you should *also* merge the `release` branch *back* to `develop`. This ensures that `develop` also acquires any `hotfixes` that may have been made.

This is illustrated in the following diagram:

[image: Git Flow]